# addEventListenerのリスナーにreactのイベント処理を登録したい

Tags: reactjs, typescript

### 疑問点

reactのReact.MouseEvent型を引数に持つイベントをeventListenerのリスナーに登録したいです。
しかしevenntListenerはmouseEvent型のリスナーを受け付けており、型が合わないためエラーが発生するようです。
エラーが発生する原因は分かったのですが、どのようにすれば型を合わせることができるのかわかりません。

※any型を使うとエラーは出ませんが、使いたくないです。

### サンプルコード

box内の領域でmouseDownしながらmouseMoveする（Box外の領域でもmouseMoveを検知したいのでdocument.addEventListenerを使っています）とコンソールにmoveと表示したいです。

Boxは`import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';`をして使っています。onMouseDown、onMouseMoveは(JSX attribute) `onMouseDown?: ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined`です。

```
 const mouseSample: React.FC = () => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
      const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
      const handleMouseDown = (): void => {
        setFlag(true);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);//イベントの型が合わないからエラーになる
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
      };
    
      const handleMouseMove = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>): void => {
        if (flag) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log('move');
        }
      };
    
      const handleMouseUp = (): void => {
        setFlag(false);
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);/イベントの型が合わないからエラーになる
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
      };
    
      return (
        <Box
          style={{
            height: '400px',
            width: '400px'
          }}
          onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
          onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
          onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
        >
          moveBox
        </Box>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Boxの定義は何でしょうか（使っているライブラリなど）？`onMouseDown` `onMouseMove`の型定義の情報があると正確に助言できると思います。

Comment: Boxはimport Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';をして使っています。
onMouseDown、onMouseMoveは(JSX attribute) onMouseDown?: ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined
です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`React.MouseEvent`は`BaseSyntheticEvent`を基底として持っており、document.addEventListenerで取得できるイベントは`nativeEvent`から取得できるので変換を行うことで型の整合性が合うと考えられます

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";

export const MouseSample: React.FC = () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
  const handleNativeMouseMove = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    if (flag) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log("move");
    }
  };
  const handleNativeMouseUp = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleNativeMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleNativeMouseUp);
    setFlag(false);
  };
  const handleNativeMouseDown = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleNativeMouseMove); /
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleNativeMouseMove);
    setFlag(true);
  };

  // 変換
  const handleMouseMove = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>): void => {
    handleNativeMouseMove(event.nativeEvent);
  };
  const handleMouseDown = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>): void => {
    handleNativeMouseDown(event.nativeEvent);
  };
  const handleMouseUp = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>): void => {
    handleNativeMouseUp(event.nativeEvent);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      style={{
        height: "400px",
        width: "400px"
      }}
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
    >
      moveBox
    </Box>
  );
};
```

### 参考

- [NativeMouseEventにMouseEventをAliasを張っている箇所](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v16/index.d.ts#L47)